# I am unable to get video tag to work when it is inside a function

Tags: html

When I call a function (myFunctions2) which has a video tag inside a function I get the error "myFunction2 is not defined", but If I use the video tag outside the function, it works.

Source:

```
<li onclick="myFunction2()">play video.</li>
<script>
  function myFunction2() {
   <video controls heights="auto"  preload="none" onclick="This.play()" >
    <source type="video/mp4" src="videos\AN01.mp4">
    <source type="video/webm" src="videos\AN01.webm">
   </video>
  }
</script>
```

Does anyone know what could cause this error?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you considered the fact that html within javascript doesnt do jack, because you need to tell javascript to dump something on your screen. Use the `innerHTML` commando or `document.write` to do something at least. `Document.write` is used for testing and it will replace html existing, i recommend you using then the `innerHTML` and specify an element where you want it in. something like `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<html here>"`

Comment: Yes, I called the document.write function and it is working now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not JavaScript.

The `<script>` element allows you to embed JavaScript in an HTML document. It is specifically designed for that purpose.

You can't just dump raw HTML into the middle of a JavaScript function. You can only write JavaScript there. The body of a JavaScript function is *not* designed to be a place for raw HTML.

MDN has some [introductory JavaScript resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) which include [a guide on manipulating the DOM of an HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

Comment: Ahhhh, I get it.  Thank you!